# pypi: how to check if the package is using wheel

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel, egg

I want to write a script which goes through all the packages on pypi repository, to check whether they are using `wheel` or `egg`.

I know that by the new standard, it is mandatory for all the packages to use `wheel` and not `egg`. I found this information on [this](https://pythonwheels.com/) website. They also have the list of packages which do and don't use `wheel`. But, they list only top few packages. But, I would like to check this for all the packages on pypi. I know that on pypi website they show if the types of files available to download e.g. [this](https://pypi.org/project/awscli-cwlogs/#files) shows that there is no wheel file type is available to download, on the contrary [this](https://pypi.org/project/asn1crypto/#files) shows that the wheel format is available to download. Does something like this help me in achieving my goal?

I certainly don't expect someone to write a script for me, but I would like a hint on how to figure if the package is using `wheel`.

Comment: Are you re-implementing [Python Wheels](https://pythonwheels.com/)?

Comment: that project checks few hundred popular packages (300/360) if they have uploaded wheel format files. I want check whole pypi repository in the similar way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PyPI has a JSON API which will give you all the releases for a given project, and all the files for a given release: https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json/

Answer (score 2):

PIP, by default, uses the [Simple PyPi Repository](https://pypi.org/simple/).

If you open the link, you can see that it has a link for every single available package.

If you open a package link, you can see different packages, versions, and download options available.

Obviously, you'll have to test for edge cases, but I should think checking if the latest version has a `.whl` extension should be a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks @Triggernometry, this seems like a better way

Comment: sorry, but I have to select @dustin Ingram's answer as it seems like way more easier.

Comment: @Ruturaj No worries! But just so you know, it's [recommended you wait for an hour or so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste) before you accept an answer, for just this reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pip download`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_download/) to download the required library, and then check if it is a wheel file or something else. But, that way, you only check the libraries available for your own distribution/OS and Python version. There may be variants…

Comment: thanks @laurent that's a good idea but rather time consuming and as you said depends on my own dist/os. But thanks anyways.